# Making lists store all data of the loop and not only last one

Tags: python, sql, api, sqlite

I want to store the JSON I get from an API, but only get the JSON of the last loop. How to get the lists dynamic? Also I need to use the last query (Pandas) but it's not working.

Last how to make an API to :

- List latest forecast for each location for every day.
- List average the_temp of last 3 forecasts for each location for every day.
- Get the top n locations based on each available metric where n is a parameter given in the API call.

```
import requests
import json
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd #library for data frame

print(sqlite3.sqlite_version)

for x in range(20,28):         # i need to get LONDjson/BERLjson/SANjson lists dynamic to store bot 7 jsons from each urls
    r = requests.get('https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/44418/2021/4/'+str(x)+'/') #GET request from the source url 
    LONDjson=r.json() #JSON object of the result
    r2 = requests.get('https://www.metaweather.com//api/location/2487956/2021/4/'+str(x)+'/')
    SANjson=r2.json()
    r3 = requests.get('https://www.metaweather.com//api/location/638242/2021/4/'+str(x)+'/')
    BERLjson=r3.json()

conn= sqlite3.connect('D:\weatherdb.db') #create db in path
cursor = conn.cursor()

#import pprint
#pprint.pprint(LONDjson)

cursor.executescript('''
                     DROP TABLE IF EXISTS LONDjson;
                     DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SANjson;
                     DROP TABLE IF EXISTS BERLjson;
                     CREATE TABLE LONDjson (id int, data json);
                     
                     ''');

for LOND in LONDjson:
    cursor.execute("insert into LONDjson values (?, ?)",
    [LOND['id'], json.dumps(LOND)])
    conn.commit()

z=cursor.execute('''select json_extract(data, '$.id', '$.the_temp', '$.weather_state_name', '$.applicable_date' ) from LONDjson;
                 ''').fetchall() #query the data
```

Answer (score 0):

hint: in your initial for loop you are not storing the results of api call. you are storing in variable but that is just getting re-written each loop.

a common solution for this starting with empty list that you append to. where perhaps if storing mutliple variables you are storing a dictionary as elements of list

example

```
results = []
for x in range(10):
    results.append(
      {
        'x': x,
        'x_sqaured': x*x,
        'abs_x': abs(x)
      }
    )
print(results)
```

Comment: Damn! Thank you now everything is inside the list! Now tho, i get an error in the line i try to insert the values to the table getting an error "list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's at least two things that can be improved in the data manipulation part of your code.

1. Using an array to store the retrieved data

```
LONDjson = []
SANjson = []
BERLjson = []

for x in range(20,28):  
    r = requests.get('https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/44418/2021/4/'+str(x)+'/')
    LONDjson.append(r.json())
    
    r2 = requests.get('https://www.metaweather.com//api/location/2487956/2021/4/'+str(x)+'/')
    SANjson.append(r2.json())
    
    r3 = requests.get('https://www.metaweather.com//api/location/638242/2021/4/'+str(x)+'/')
    BERLjson.append(r3.json())
```

2. Retrieving the data from the array

```
# The retrieved data is a dictionary inside a list with only one entry
for LOND in LONDjson:
    print(LOND[0]['id'])
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Yes thats what i did in order to store all the info. Each list is a day and the dictionary has the info of each day(the weather-72 dictionaries). Now that i executed the List i have problems importing it to my database.

Comment: when i try to insert the values in the "or LOND in LONDjson:
    cursor.execute("insert into LONDjson values (?, ?)",
    [LOND['id'], json.dumps(LOND)])" part  i get an error "list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Comment: @nullboyForINT , maybe if you try this it'll work:

**cursor.execute("insert into LONDjson values (?, ?)", [LOND[0]['id'], json.dumps(LOND[0])])**

Comment: you are a god! i was trying  [LOND[0]['id'], json.dumps(LOND)]) and got the same error. So what exactly is happening with this command? Does the db gets values in the table with the primary key id? I guess i have to make a loop to store everything inside

Comment: If the database explicitly requires an integer, you can insert a cast with int() like this: **int(LOND[0]['id'])**